# How to apply CAML query on the Calculated Column of the list?

Tags: caml-query, calculated-column

I have a calculated column that stores the calculated date value.

When I apply the CAML query, it does not return any row even if the record exists.

Comment: Hi Mansi. I know it has been a while since you posted this question but I recently had a scenario similar to yours. The only way I solved it was to first load ALL the list items within the list into a ListItemCollection specifying the fields making up the Calculated column in the <ViewFields>, and then I used LINQ on all the ListItemCollection whilst at the same time re-creating the Calculated column within the query. I could post an answer with more detail if this is still a problem for anyone or if anyone is interested to know more about my "solution"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Value Type equals your `OutputType` rather than `Calculated` in CAML query.

```
// This will not work >> <Value Type='Calculated'>my value</Value>

// Following will work
<Where>
  <Contains>
    <FieldRef Name='FullName' />
      <Value Type='Text'>my value</Value>
  </Contains>
</Where>
```

Read this link: [CAML Query on Calculated Fields](https://sptalks.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/query-on-calculated-field-problem/)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I had recreated this problem and Calculated fields never returned results for me, even if I was sure they existed within the list/library.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to what you use as value type in your CAML.  The type must be the return type of your calculation for example it might be 'Number'

Answer (score 0):

I used the `FieldInternalName` instead of the custom name of the field to make the Ronak Patel's solution working.

Who could not make it work:

The caluclated SharePoint field also has `FieldInternalName` which is generated at the first time when the field is created.

Once the field is renamed then the `FieldName` is changing accordingly, but the `FieldInternalName` not. You can get the calc field `FieldInternalName` from the display form by F12 - developer tool selecting calculated field element `td#SPFieldCalculated` as this field type is not visible on the New or Edit Forms.