# CAML Query on a Lookup Field that points to a Calculated Field throws Exception

Tags: caml-query, lookup-column, calculated-column

I wrote some CAML Queries to get data from a List that has lookups on another List. All is working fine as long as I do not reference a Lookup Field which points to a Calculated Field.

I tried different types in the value field, but it just doesn't work. When I replace the FieldRef with another field from the list, it works as excpected.
Why can't I use a lookup to a calculated Field in a Query?

Definition of the to-be-queried Lookup Field in `List A`

```
<Field Name="Mitarbeiter" ShowField="Search" ID="{...}" DisplayName="Mitarbeiter" Type="Lookup" List="Lists/Mitarbeiter" />
```

The referenced calculated Field in `List B` (basically displays "Lastname, Firstname" in this example)

```
<Field Name="Search" ID="{...}" Hidden="FALSE" DisplayName="Search" Type="Calculated" ResultType="Text" ReadOnly="TRUE">
   <FieldRefs>
     <FieldRef Name="Title" />
     <FieldRef Name="Vorname" />
   </FieldRefs>
   <Formula>=Title &amp; ", " &amp; Vorname</Formula>
</Field>
```

and the CAML Query (Field `Mitarbeiter` Points to a calculated Field in another List)

```
 <Where>
  <Contains>
     <FieldRef Name="Mitarbeiter" />
     <Value Type="Text">Name of person</Value>
  </Contains>
 </Where>
```

The Request crashes and I find several entries in the SP Logs

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of like function.

Unknown SQL Exception 8116 occurred.  Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of like function.function.'
```

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: No nothing so far. I had to solve my problem differently. But I still hope someone has an answer for me.

Comment: Have you seen this? Looks like similar problem: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41435/how-to-apply-caml-query-on-the-calculated-column-of-the-list

Comment: Thanks, but no its not the same problem but it has something to do with it. And I already tried different (all possible) value types for the return value. The normal Calculated Column does work, the problem is if I have a Lookup on this Calculated Field and want to query that Lookup Field.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 <Where>
  <Contains>
     <FieldRef Name="Mitarbeiter" />
     <Value Type="lookup">ID of person</Value>
  </Contains>
 </Where>
```

or

```
     <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name="Mitarbeiter" />
         <Value Type="lookupId">ID of person</Value>
      </Contains>
     </Where>
```